# Tengo dudas de como usar .text en javascript para mandar un valor a html error Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, html5, typescript

Tengo esta linea de codigo en un file de tipo js se llama acerca.js
`console.log(contador); \\contador puede ser cualquier numero`  en el index.html tengo
`<p>eventos completados: <span class="completos">???</span> </p>`
Como puedo hacer para mandar ese valor a la class de html "completos" para que me imprima el valor del contador. Ya e intentado esta linea pero no funciona
`$('.completos').text(contador);` me da error Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: $ is not defined.

En mi html tengo el script requerido
`<script type="text/javascript" src="js/acerca.js"></script>`

Gracias!

Comment: Intenta poner los fragmentos de código correspondientes, porque quizá no has requerido el archivo js correspondiente en el html. Edita la pregunta y pega el código del html y del js por favor, será más fácil de saber lo que pides y dónde estará el fallo.

Comment: ¿De dónde tomas el valor de contador? Este ejemplo mínimo funciona: `var contador=5; console.log(contador); $('.completos').text(contador);` Activa la consola de Javascript y revisa si hay errores allí.

Comment: el valor del contador viene de un switch statement basado en un typescript. Puse el console.log para comprobar que si imprime un valor en la consola.

Comment: ¿Y, se imprime un valor en la consola o no? Por otra parte, el error *$ is not defined* suele ocurrir cuando intentas usar jQuery sin haberlo incluido antes.

Comment: si imprime el valor en la consola. es posible agregar el jQuery en el js file? No debo editar o agregar cosas al html file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucionado.
Esto me funciono.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('completos')[0].innerHTML = contador;
```

Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

revisa si tienes jQuery incluido ya que te da error por el objeto jQuery ($) puedes probar incluyendolo con su CDN

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc="crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```